# When are Stemmers used in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am confused about when stemmers are used in ElasticSearch.

In the `Dealing with Human Language/Reducing Words to Their Root Form` section I see that stemmers are used to strip words into their root forms.  This lead me to believe that Stemmers were used as a token filter on an analyzer.

But a token filter only filters the token, does not actually reduce words to their root forms.

So, where are stemmers used?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can do stemming with a token filter in an analyzer. That is exactly how stemming works in ES. Have a look at the [documentation for Stemmer Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html).

ES also provides the [Snowball Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-snowball-analyzer.html), which is a convenient analyzer to use for stemming.

Otherwise, if there is a different type of stemming you would like to use, you can always build your own [Custom Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html). This gives you complete control over the stemming solution that works best for you, as [discussed here in the guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/choosing-a-stemmer.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see.  So, stemming is not a thing you can declare to use.  Stemming is just a processes and some Token Filters use Stemming.  I see.  Thank you.